# Does "Sadgati" mean a more fortunate/higher birth in one's next life?

Tags: sanskrit

Due to good deeds and such. Puri Shankaracharya mentioned this word in one of his videos.

Comment: Reference to the word can be found in the following links (quite possible there are more posts) too: (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46295/aputrasya-gatir-naasti-svargo-naivaca-naivaca/46311#46311), (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35418/4732).

Comment: @Rickross still didnt understand

Comment: Gati means movement. And Sad/Sath here means right/correct. So the word means movement towards the right direction. Which basically means the journey of the soul towards the right direction or higher realms. It can also mean Moksha (liberation) depending on the context it is used in.

Comment: THanks @Rickross